# How to make Multiple Database Query in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to make a query from multiple Databases.

```
$data = Product::select([
    'products.id',
    'products.name',
    'products.price',
    DB::raw(
        DB::connection('mysql2')
            ->select('select  count(*) from product_groups where product_groups.main_product=?', [21])
    )
])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
        $data = Product::select(['products.id',
                             'products.name',
                             'products.price',
                              DB::raw('(select count(*) from db2.product_groups where db2.product_groups.main_product=products.id) as nbr')
                             ])->get();
```